# Calculate Events Duration in a day using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have the following pandas dataframe, the duration is espressed in Minutes:

```
Start Date             Event    Duration
2021.01.01 00:00 AM     2        540
2021.01.01 9:00 AM      1        180 
2021.01.01 12:00 PM     2        20
2021.01.01 12:20 PM     1        1440
2021.01.02 12:20 PM     2        60
2021.01.02 1:20 PM      1        20
```

I would like to calculate the duration of each event for a single day. The problem is that there are some event like the one in line 3 that are across multiple days.
What I would like to obtain is something like this:

```
Date           Event    Duration
2021.01.01       1        880 
2021.01.01       2        560
2021.01.02       1        760
2021.01.02       2        60
```

In general the sum of all events in a specific day cannot exceed 1440 which is 24 hours * 60 minutes. The event are continuous so there is alway an event, there are never times without events.

Comment: Is the duration correct in the expected output? Should it be `[880, 560, 760, 60]`

Answer (score 1):

For some weird reasons I could not convert your dates right away but needed to replace whitespaces. Nonetheless, let’s start by converting your `Date` column to pandas dates and set it as an index:

```
>>> df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'].str.replace(r'\s+', ' ', regex=True))
>>> df = df.set_index('Start Date')
>>> df
                     Event  Duration
2021-01-01 00:00:00      2       540
2021-01-01 09:00:00      1       180
2021-01-01 12:00:00      2        20
2021-01-01 12:20:00      1      1440
2021-01-02 12:20:00      2        60
2021-01-02 13:20:00      1        20
```

We can then compute which splits need to be done, aka timestamps where the day changes but that don’t appear as `Start Date`, and add those to the index:

```
>>> splits = pd.date_range(df.index.min().floor(freq='D') + pd.Timedelta(days=1), df.index.max().ceil(freq='D') - pd.Timedelta(days=1), freq='D')
>>> df = df.reindex(df.index.append(splits).drop_duplicates().sort_values())
>>> df
                     Event  Duration
2021-01-01 00:00:00    2.0     540.0
2021-01-01 09:00:00    1.0     180.0
2021-01-01 12:00:00    2.0      20.0
2021-01-01 12:20:00    1.0    1440.0
2021-01-02 00:00:00    NaN       NaN
2021-01-02 12:20:00    2.0      60.0
2021-01-02 13:20:00    1.0      20.0
```

At this point we know it’s the difference between indexes that’s the time we want. Fill in the blanks from `Duration`, then we can simply group by day/event and sum without any unexpected behaviour:

```
>>> minutes = df.index.to_series().diff().shift(-1).astype('timedelta64[m]').fillna(df['Duration'])
>>> minutes
2021-01-01 00:00:00    540.0
2021-01-01 09:00:00    180.0
2021-01-01 12:00:00     20.0
2021-01-01 12:20:00    700.0
2021-01-02 00:00:00    740.0
2021-01-02 12:20:00     60.0
2021-01-02 13:20:00     20.0
dtype: float64
>>> minutes.groupby([df.index.date, df['Event'].ffill()]).sum()
            Event
2021-01-01  1.0      880.0
            2.0      560.0
2021-01-02  1.0      760.0
            2.0       60.0
dtype: float64
```

Note that we also made sure to propagate event ids to the split lines with `.ffill()`

This solution has the advantage of not generating huge dataframes with 1 entry per minute, and without limits on how many days can be contained in a single `Duration` value.

Comment: Hi, your solution partially works, the main problem is that as you can see on 2021-01-02, the event 1 Duration should be 760, since the event of the previous day continue in the next day

Comment: @MarcoMiglionico there’s a missing `.ffill()` on `df['Event']`, I’ll fix it

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution but it is a starting point

```
# convert to datetime
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
# calculate the end date
df['End Date'] = df['Start Date'] + df['Duration'].apply(pd.Timedelta, unit='min')
# create a mask to filter your frame where start date is not the same as end date
same_day_mask = df['Start Date'].dt.date != df['End Date'].dt.date
# create two new frames
same_day_df = df[~same_day_mask].copy()
not_same_day_df = df[same_day_mask].copy()
# calculate the time it takes to get to midnight the next day
not_same_day_df['day1'] = (not_same_day_df['End Date'].dt.normalize() - not_same_day_df['Start Date']).dt.total_seconds()/60
# Calculate the remaining time from duration 
not_same_day_df['day2'] = not_same_day_df['Duration'] - not_same_day_df['day1']
# reasign value to duration
not_same_day_df['Duration'] = not_same_day_df['day1']
not_same_day_df['Event2'] = not_same_day_df['Event']
new = not_same_day_df[['End Date', 'day2', 'Event2']].rename(columns={'End Date': 'Start Date',
                                                                      'day2': 'Duration',
                                                                      'Event2': 'Event'})
# append the data frames together
final_df = same_day_df.append(not_same_day_df[not_same_day_df.columns[:3]].append(new))
# groupby and sum
print(final_df.groupby([final_df['Start Date'].dt.normalize(), 'Event'])['Duration'].sum().reset_index())

  Start Date  Event  Duration
0 2021-01-01      1     880.0
1 2021-01-01      2     560.0
2 2021-01-02      1     760.0
3 2021-01-02      2      60.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating date ranges with `pd.date_range`, `explode` and `groupby`:

```
df["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start Date"])

df["TimeRange"] = [
    pd.date_range(s, periods=m, freq="T")
    for s, m in zip(df["Start Date"], df["Duration"])
]

df_out = (
    df.explode("TimeRange")
      .groupby(["Event", pd.Grouper(key="TimeRange", freq="D")]['Event']
      .count().rename('Duration').reset_index()
)

df_out
```

Output:

```
   Event  TimeRange  Duration
0      1 2021-01-01       880
1      1 2021-01-02       760
2      2 2021-01-01       560
3      2 2021-01-02        60
```

Create an record by minute starting with Start Date then count the records and groupby event and date.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html%5D)

for example you could calculate the sum of all durations on a day like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io


df = """
Date Time             Event    Duration
2021.01.01 00:00 AM     2        540
2021.01.01 9:00 AM      1        180 
2021.01.01 12:00 PM     2        20
2021.01.01 12:20 PM     1        1440
2021.01.02 12:20 PM     2        60
2021.01.02 1:20 PM      1        20
"""

df = df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df), sep=r"\s+")

df.reset_index().groupby(["index", "Event"]).sum()
```

```py
>>>                   Duration
>>> index      Event          
>>> 2021.01.01 1          1620
>>>            2           560
>>> 2021.01.02 1            20
>>>            2            60
```